# Netty 4.0 SO_Keeplive one connection send many request to server How to process request concurrently

Tags: sockets, concurrency, netty

one connection send many request to server

How to process request concurrently.

Please use a simple example like timeserver or echoserver in netty.io
to illustrate the operation.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could find out is to create a separate threaded handler that will be called as in a producer/consumer way.

The producer will be your "network" handler, giving message to the consumers, therefore not waiting for any wanswear and being able then to proceed with the next request.

The consumer will be your "business" handler, one per connection but possibly multi-threaded, consuming with multiple instances the messages and being able to answer using the Netty's context from the connection from which it is attached.

Another option for the consumer would be to have only one handler, still multi-threaded, but then message will come in with the original Netty's Context such that it can answear to the client, whatever the connection attached.

But the difficulties will come soon:

- How to deal with an answear among several requests on client side: let say the client sends 3 requests A, B and C and the answears will come back, due to speed of the Business handler, as C, A, B... You have to deal with it, and knowing for which request the answer is.
- You have to ensure all the ways the context given in parameter is still valid (channel active), if you don't want to have too many errors.

Perhaps the best way would be to however handle your request in order (as Netty does), and keep the answear's action as quick as possible.